# How do non airbenders determine who is the avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

The airbenders would use toys to determine the next avatar .  How do the other nations determine the avatar?
For example how was it determined Korra was the next avatar?

Comment: Watch the first scene of the first episode of *The Legend of Korra*, it explains the second part of your question.

Comment: I believe with Korra they determined it because as a young child she announced "I'm the Avatar, you gotta deal with it!" and did Earth, Fire, and Waterbending in front of them.  But it's a good general question. ;)

Comment: https://youtu.be/bMnzrUrzX8Q

Comment: Do we know that only the Airbenders used the toy test?  The toys Aang chose were the same as the toys that previous Avatars chose.  They did not say previous Air nomad Avatars, so it is entirely possible that all nations used this test.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster hmm its a monk thing in real life so I would assume it also just a monk thing in the tv show.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in [The Lost Scrolls:
 Air](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Scrolls#The_Lost_Scrolls:_Air), it is mentioned that the Avatar Relics belonged specifically to Air Nomad Avatars, so this method of identifying the Avatar was used only by Air Nomads, and was therefore only employed following the death of a Fire Avatar.

Comment: Though they are Nomads, it could theoretically be that they would take the relics to various lands who are expecting an Avatar and help them test people.